# How to cast timestamptz to timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

How can I cast timestamptz to timestamp using python?
values can be: 2013-09-27 14:19:46.825000+02:00, 2019-09-21 13:19:10.
This row doesn't work for me.

**Code**

```
tab[timestamp(self.date_)] > timestamp(max_date)
```

Comment: could you be more specific on the data structure? Are you having a pandas df or a list oder just a variable? Are the values comming from an postgresql data source (which has timestamptz as data type) or a csv file or else? In your line, there is no cast, so what did you try to achieve there?

Comment: The values are coming from postgres tables and are of type timestamptz.

Comment: tab[jptz.localize(self.date_)]  > jptz.localize(max_date)

Answer (score 0):

assuming you either use psycopg2 or sqlalchemy to fetch everything into a pandas df, the following should work. (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for reference)

```
df["timestamp_transformed"] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
```

I tested this based on a string, because I have the experience that the export from postgresql creates an object column that can be treated like a string.

```
test = "2021-03-26 16:08:12+02:00"

test_but_as_datetime = pd.to_datetime(test)
print(test_but_as_datetime)
```

```
out:
    2021-03-26 16:08:12+02:00
```

pandas recognizes the tz. Hence, you can convert the tz to whatever you want:

```
test_but_in_utc = test_but_as_datetime.tz_convert("UTC")
print(test_but_in_utc)
```

```
out:
    2021-03-26 14:08:12+00:00
```

When you do this on a pandas column or a self-standing pandas series, you have to use a `.dt` at the end of the series.

```
test_series = pd.Series(["2021-03-26 16:08:12+02:00", "2021-03-25 16:08:12+02:00"])
test_series_but_as_datetime = pd.to_datetime(test_series)
# in this line you find the .dt that I was mentioning
print(test_series_but_as_datetime.dt.tz_convert("UTC"))
```

```
out:
0   2021-03-26 14:08:12+00:00
1   2021-03-25 14:08:12+00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but my column is of type timeztamptz not timestamp

Comment: have you casted the column to string and tried the above?